# List all NEWS from previously updated packages

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I would like to be able to list all the NEWS from packages that have been upgraded since I last ran the script/command. This would then likely be run in a cron job once per week in order to provide a summary of any upgrade information.

The `apt-listchanges` command looks like what I want, but I can't seem to get it to behave exactly as I described. The command I've tried running is:

```
apt-listchanges -f text -a --which=news --save_seen=/var/lib/apt/listchanges.db /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
```

It seems to want the actual packages to be listed, rather than just checking all of them by default, so I gave it everything in the cache, I'm not sure if that is the best way to do that.

But, the bigger problem, is that by default it only shows changes between the currently installed versions, therefore shows no changes. Therefore I added the -a option to display all changes, and then added the save_seen option which claims that it will stop it displaying changes that have been previously shown. But, each time I run the command it displays all the changes every time.

Is there a way to tweak the command to work as expected? Or, maybe some other solution, such as using an apt hook to append the NEWS for each upgraded package to a file, then my script can simply read the file and delete the contents each time it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two approaches which don’t involve tweaking `apt-listchanges` too much. Both rely on the default `apt-listchanges` hook in `apt`; check that `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges` exists on your system. This works nicely because `apt-listchanges` is run with the list of packages which `apt` is about to upgrade, and can thus compare the current installed versions with these. (`apt-listchanges`’ design makes it difficult to run after the fact; you could use the `--since` option but you’d need to keep track of the appropriate values.)

The first approach is to configure `apt-listchanges` to send an email with any changes. This needs a working mail setup on the system, which might not be convenient for you; but I find it very handy. In the `[apt]` section of `/etc/apt/listchanges.conf`, set `frontend=mail`, and `email_address` as appropriate; then `apt-listchanges` will run every time `apt` runs, and send an email containing the news items (and/or changelogs, depending on the `which` setting).

The second, which I haven’t actually tried, is to configure `apt-listchanges` to simply dump news entries and/or changelogs to its standard output, and redirect that to a log file which you can then read whenever convenient. In the `[apt]` section of `/etc/apt/listchanges.conf`, set `frontend=text`; in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges`, add an appending redirection to your target file.

Comment: I've been testing out the second option, and I think I have it working. The only problem is that even when there is nothing to display it does still append "apt-listchanges: Reading changelogs..." to the file. Is that something that can be suppressed?

Comment: For anyone wanting to try this, the changed line in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges` is:
`DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs { "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt >> /var/lib/apt/listchanges-news || test $? -lt 10"; };`

Comment: Try the `-q` option (perhaps doubled), I think it will disable the “Reading changelogs” message.